# How to use Pandas to fill some cells with a defined rule?

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, fillna

This's a sample data from real.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'P/N':['302-462-326','302-462-012','302-462-009'],
                  'Description':['CAP CER 0402 100pF 5% 50V','CAP CER 0402 6.8pF 0.25pF 50V','CAP CER 0402 3.9pF 0.25pF 50V'],
                  'Supplier.0':['MURATA','AVX Corporation','AVX Corporation'],
                  'Supplier PN.0':['GRM1555C1H101JA01D',np.nan,'04025A3R9CAT2A'],
                  'Supplier.1':[np.nan,'KEMET',np.nan],
                  'Supplier PN.1':['CC0402JRNPO9BN101','C0402C689C5GACTU',np.nan],
                  'Supplier.2':['Murata Electronics North America',np.nan,np.nan],
                  'Supplier PN.2':['GRM1555C1H101JA01J',np.nan,np.nan]
                  })
```

The **Supplier** and **Supplier PN** are paired up in the columns. The requirement is that if one of the **Supplier** and **supplier PN** is empty, but another one isn't empty, then we must fill 'NOT CLEAR' in the empty cell. 
We need to keep the cell to be empty when both of the Supplier and Supplier PN are empty.
[image]

> How to use Pandas to get the expected result which just as the picture
>   below？Thanks.
>
> The real data has many rows and columns may be reached to Supplier.20
>   and Supplier PN.20.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be unpivotting using [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) the dataframe and then check if sum of notna is 1 then fillna else dont , and pivot back again, this would help if you have many combinations of Supplier and Supplier PN.

```
unpivotted_df = (pd.wide_to_long(df,['Supplier','Supplier PN'],
                 ['P/N','Description'],'idx',sep='.'))

cond = unpivotted_df.notna().sum(1).eq(1)
unpivotted_df[:]=np.where(cond[:,None],unpivotted_df.fillna('NOT CLEAR'),unpivotted_df)
out = unpivotted_df.unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1).reindex(df[['P/N','Description']])
out.columns=out.columns.map('{0[0]}.{0[1]}'.format)
```

---

[image]

This is how the `unpivoted_df` looks like after the `fillna`:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Loop through relevant Supplier columns and use np.where and .isna() / .notna()

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'P/N':['302-462-326','302-462-012','302-462-009'],
          'Description':['CAP CER 0402 100pF 5% 50V',
          'CAP CER 0402 6.8pF 0.25pF 50V',
          'CAP CER 0402 3.9pF 0.25pF 50V'],
          'Supplier.0':['MURATA','AVX Corporation','AVX Corporation'],
          'Supplier PN.0':['GRM1555C1H101JA01D',np.nan,'04025A3R9CAT2A'],
          'Supplier.1':[np.nan,'KEMET',np.nan],
          'Supplier PN.1':['CC0402JRNPO9BN101','C0402C689C5GACTU',np.nan],
          'Supplier.2':['Murata Electronics North America',np.nan,np.nan],
          'Supplier PN.2':['GRM1555C1H101JA01J',np.nan,np.nan]
          })
cols = df.columns
i, j = 0, 0
for col in cols:
    if 'Supplier.' in col:
        col_var1 = f'Supplier.{i}'
        col_var2 = f'Supplier PN.{i}'
        df[col_var1] = np.where(df[col_var1].isna() & df[col_var2].notna(),
                                'NOT CLEAR',
                                df[col_var1])
        i += 1
    elif 'Supplier PN.' in col:
        col_var1 = f'Supplier.{j}'
        col_var2 = f'Supplier PN.{j}'
        df[col_var2] = np.where(df[col_var2].isna() & df[col_var1].notna(),
                                'NOT CLEAR',
                                df[col_var2])
        j += 1
df
```

Comment: Thanks. But actually there are many columns, lots of Supplier and Supplier PN. Any method to deal with the whole instead of each column?

Comment: @Ringo please mark as answer if this new edited code with looping is the ideal solution you were looking for.